# Java - instanceof returning false when should be true

Tags: java, class, casting

So basically, im implementing interface in a view, then pass the view as source of custom event, in one of 3 "instanceof" calls it return false.

View:

```
public class NamedOffensiveStatsView extends BagVectorPanel implements INamedOffensiveStatsView {
```

Event.toString():

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(this.getSource().getClass() + ": ");
```

e.toString() prints:

```
class pl.drag0nius.diablo3.DPSCalc.NamedOffensiveStats.NamedOffensiveStatsView$2
```

instanceof returning false:

```
@Override
public void eventFired(Event e) {
    logger.debug("eventFired: " + e.toString());
    if (e.getSource() instanceof INamedOffensiveStatsView) {
```

Also i cannot cast from view to it's interface.

Answer:

With help of my friend we found the issue.

The code calling event (inside initComponents() of view):

```
    jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (comboBoxReady) {
                logger.debug("actionPerformed");
                listener.eventFired(new Event(this, "selection", jComboBox.getSelectedIndex()));
            }
        }
    });
```

What it should be:

```
    jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (comboBoxReady) {
                logger.debug("actionPerformed");
                listener.eventFired(new Event(NamedOffensiveStatsView.this, "selection", jComboBox.getSelectedIndex()));
            }
        }
    });
```

"this" was referencing nested class, not the view.

Comment: Is e.getSource()==null where instanceof returns false?

Comment: I think you should put your edits as an answer and accepts your own answer.

Comment: the thing is i cant answer my own questions during first 10 hours after posting or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `$2` at the end of the classname indicates that the source seems to be an anonymous innerclass of `NamedOffensiveStatsView`.  It therefore would not be an instance of `NamedOffensiveStatsView`